# ArcGIS map with basemap toggle and simplemarker pointer

Tags: php, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using ArcGIS map which gives me an error:

[image]

Below is my function which i am using to implementing the map on my
application:

```
function handlerForVariableB (latt, longt, complaintid)
{


  // execute code that is relevant when "$a" was set on the server-side. 
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "tools/nrega_v2.1/map.php",
    data: 'complaintid='+complaintid,
    success: function(data){         
      var data_array = JSON.parse(data);


  $('.modal-info').html("");

  var hrymap='<div id="hrymap"></div>';
    $(".modal-info").append(hrymap);

  $('#hrymap').html(""); 

    $('#hrymap').html("<div id='map' style='width:850px;height:650px;'><div id='BasemapToggle'></div></div>");
          //var map;

      var map;

     require([
        "esri/map", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/graphic", 
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer", "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol","esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer","esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map,  MapView,
  BasemapToggle,Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Graphic, GraphicsLayer,PictureMarkerSymbol,ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer
      ) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "<?php echo $basemap; ?>",
      center: [longt,latt],
          zoom: "<?php echo $zoomlevel; ?>",

        });
         var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: [-86.049, 38.485],
    zoom: 3
  });

  // 1 - Create the widget
  var toggle = new BasemapToggle({
    // 2 - Set properties
    view: view, // view that provides access to the map's 'topo' basemap
    nextBasemap: "hybrid" // allows for toggling to the 'hybrid' basemap
  });
 view.ui.add(toggle, "top-right");

        map.on("load", function() {
          var gl = new GraphicsLayer();
          var p = new Point(longt,latt);

     var s = new PictureMarkerSymbol('img/location.png', 51, 51);

          var g = new Graphic(p, s);
          gl.add(g);
          map.addLayer(gl);
          map.addLayer(new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer('<?php echo $roadlayers; ?>'));

                    });
      });

     $("#detail_content").css({'display':'block'});



    }
  });



}
```

Below are the js and css which are using in my application:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- jvectormap -->
   <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
<link href="css/custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/style.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="leafletslib/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="leafletslib/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.crypt.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.validarium.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.29/esri/css/esri.css">
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.29/"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are trying to load `esri/views/MapView` from the wrong version of ArcGIS Javascript API. This [class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html) exists on version 4.x of the API, not 3.29.

Comment: I am getting the same error with 4.11 version

Comment: Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.js”.

Comment: Once again, you're mixing up classes from two different versions. `esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` belongs to version 3.x. You should decide which version you want to use and then find the relevant classes from API. Use the documentation: [v3.x](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/) or [v4.x](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/index.html)

Comment: i need actually basemap toggle with simplemarker please suggest me which relevan class i use to achieve my requirement

Comment: You can use any of them, just be consistent. You can use 4.x, but you have to go over your code and make sure the classes and methods exist and that you're using the right syntax. For example, replace `esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` with `esri/layers/MapImageLayer` and use `map.add()` instead of `map.addLayer()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96510/discussion-between-sumit-kundan-and-isshp).